# How to manipulate and extract certain data from a table?

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I am quite new to Linux.
I have data like the following, it is in a tbl format

```
>Feature gnl|XXX|IFEJKLFI_79
            locus_tag   IFEJKLFI_05549
            locus_tag   IFEJKLFI_05549
            protein_id  gnl|XXX|IFEJKLFI_05549

>Feature gnl|XXX|IFEJKLFI_88
            locus_tag   IFEJKLFI_05553
            locus_tag   IFEJKLFI_05553
            protein_id  gnl|XXX|IFEJKLFI_05553
```

I want to extract locus_tag name and match it with the feature name.
To elaborate more, I would like the output to look like that

```
Feature gnl|XXX|IFEJKLFI_79     IFEJKLFI_05549
Feature gnl|XXX|IFEJKLFI_88     IFEJKLFI_05553
```

Is that possible to use the awk command directly or should I manipulate the data first?
And if yes, how to extract the data?

Thanks!!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `it is in a tbl format` - the text you show doesn't look like the input to or the output from the Unix command [tbl](https://www.unix.com/man-page/v7/1/tbl/) as far as I remember (but I haven't used it in about 15 years so I may be forgetting something), nor (if you're trying to save 2 chars by saying `tbl` instead of `table`) does it look like tab-separated data, nor it is a visually aligned in tabular format.

Comment: Are the `>` part of your file? Is that really the _exact_ format you are dealing with? I ask because this looks like it should be a genbank flat file, which doesn't have `>` and for which there are dedicated parsers.

Comment: Yes ">" is a part of my file. I added another question but in the answer form, could you please have a look at it? Thanks!!

Comment: Are the "locus-tag-like" patterns (e.g. `IFEJKLFI_05549` in your first record) allways the same _within the same `Feature`_? That is important because if that is true it doesn't matter if we take it from line 2 or 3 (or 4, for that matter) of the `Feature` record. If there can be different `locus_tag`s, which one should we take?

Comment: Yes, under each Feature there are different "locus-tags", but I am interested in some of them and I need to know to which "Feature" the "locus-tag" of interest belongs.

Comment: Does [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/716203/133219) do what you wanted then? Best I can tell it produces exactly the output you asked for given the sample input you provided.

Comment: I see you posted a followup question on a different forum, https://stackoverflow.com/q/73621316/1745001, without showing them your current code or referring to this question for background. Why not stick to following up in this forum where you already have people trying to help you and asking questions about your data?

Comment: Your answer helped me and I am really grateful to you, but afterwards, I wanted to extract the data according to specific criteria and I could not add the follow-up question. Also, I tried to put it as an answer, but the admin deleted it. Sorry for that but this is the first time I ask questions through this platform. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk if you really do have blank lines between each block of data as shown in your sample input:

```
$ awk -v RS= '{print $1, $2, $4}' file
>Feature gnl|XXX|IFEJKLFI_79 IFEJKLFI_05549
>Feature gnl|XXX|IFEJKLFI_88 IFEJKLFI_05553
```

or this if the locus_tag line is always immediately after the feature line as shown in your sample input:

```
$ awk '/^>/{feat=$0; n=0} ++n==2{print feat, $2}' file
>Feature gnl|XXX|IFEJKLFI_79 IFEJKLFI_05549
>Feature gnl|XXX|IFEJKLFI_88 IFEJKLFI_05553
```

or this otherwise:

```
$ awk '/^>/{feat=$0; f=1} f && $1=="locus_tag"{print feat, $2; f=0}' file
>Feature gnl|XXX|IFEJKLFI_79 IFEJKLFI_05549
>Feature gnl|XXX|IFEJKLFI_88 IFEJKLFI_05553
```